# Is there anything different with "System.out.println(a+"\n")" and "System.out.println(a); System.out.println();"?

Tags: java, algorithm, enter, println

Recently I'm trying to solve an algorithm exercise on Hangdian OJ(1001).
When I eventually write `System.out.println(a+"\n")` , the OJ responsed **Presentation Error(means wrong format for outputing)** to me. 
However, it's amazingly OK after I changed the codes to `System.out.println(a);  System.out.println();`
I just don't understand the differences bettween theses 2 sentences-In my mind their functions are absolutely quite the same.
Ask for help, please.
Here are the exercise descriptions and my codes:

```java
package forJava.HangdianOJ.AplusBPractices.AplusB1001;

/**
        **@description
 **Hey,welcome to HDOJ(Hangzhou Dianzi University Online Judge).
         **
         **In this problem,your task is to calculate SUM(n)=1+2+3+...+n.
         **
         **
         **Input
         **The input will consist of a series of integers n,one integer per line.
         **
         **
         **Output
         **For each case,output SUM(n)in one line,followed by a blank line.
         **You may assume the result will be in the range of 32-bit signed integer.
         **
         **
 * Sample Input
 * 1
 * 100
 *
 *
 * Sample Output
 * 1
 *
 * 5050
 */

import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner  = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a = 0;
        while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
            // System.out.println(sumOfSeries(scanner.nextInt())+"\n"); // ——wrong

            // ——OK
            System.out.println(sumOfSeries(scanner.nextInt()));
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
    private static int sumOfSeries(int n) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            sum+=i;
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: `println` uses OS dependent line separator so for Windows it would add `\r\n` serie not only `\n`.

Comment: @Pshemo Thanks a lot !  
After I added `"\r"` before `"\n",`  it really worked !

Comment: But then it will be wrong if your code runs on Linux.

Comment: You should use the second form, which gives you the platform behaviour for both newlines. The first form gives you a combination of whatever newline sequence you hard-wired into the literal and the platform behaviour. Not a happy situation.

Comment: You can also use `System.lineSeparator()` to get the platform-dependent line separator, to use in place of `"\n"` or `"\r\n"`.

Comment: @Andreas Thank you for warning. I have promoted my code.

Comment: @AndyTurner. Got it. Thanks a lot!